# Count how many times person appears during one hour

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I would like to count how many people appears during one hour while creating unique package heavier than 5kg.

For example:
X is gathering items into one package. At 4/30/2020 11:10 he picked item with weight 3kg into Y and at 11:30 he picked item with weight 4 kg into Y. That gives us one package Y over 5kg. Then he picked 4kg into new package Z at 11:45 and 2kg at 12:05 -> another package over 5kg. Now I would expect to see:

```
ID - Packages heavier than 5kg during 1 hour
X - 2
Q - 4
U - 4
```

SQL sentence that I've used below. I don't know how to count based on mentioned conditions.

```
SELECT timestamp,
       ID,
       package
FROM table
GROUP by timestamp,id,package
HAVING SUM(weight) >= 5000
```

Comment: Sample data as a *text* table is much more useful than a long paragraph.  And how do you identify the "person"?

Comment: I have different ID for each person like X,Q,U. What I need to obtain is how many occurrence I had where person with specific ID had to create package above 5kg in an hour more than 2 times.

Comment: . . Explain the data *in the question* not in a comment.  Sample data, desired results, and clear explanations (that match!) would really help.